# android media player playing trailers

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to play the above trailer using following code but it is not working throwing following error

Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info PVMFFailure
02-02 13:40:33.696: ERROR/MediaPlayer(805): error (1, -1)
02-02 13:40:33.706: ERROR/MediaPlayer(805): Error (1,-1)

Trailler link = http://uk.clip-1.filmtrailer.com/3230_8406_a_4.wmv?log_var=103|441100218-1|-

```
private final void playTrailler(String url)throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException {
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        Log.v(TAG, "Trailler: " + url);
        mp.setDataSource(url);
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mp.prepareAsync();
    }


public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();

    }
```

Comment: Does it work without the `?log...` querystring? Also, note that according to the supported media formats doc, WMV 'versions 7, 8 and 9. Simple profile only' are supported: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html